# What to do With Question that involved a ubuntu wiki link?

Tags: discussion, support, community-wiki, link

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Answers based on Ubuntu wiki](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1052/answers-based-on-ubuntu-wiki)

Days ago I saw an answer that involved a ubuntu wiki link, the question was:

How to setup a DNS server ?

the answer was :

you can follow this wonderful guide in our ubuntu wiki :

[Domain Name Service (DNS)](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/serverguide/dns.html)

after a few days the answer received a comment :

> Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be
>   preferable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the
>   essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for
>   reference.

in this answer, is hard to do a brief because the link have a lot of useful information in it, also the community improve this wiki, but in the community wiki is rarely happen a [linkrot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkrot)....

What to do in this case where a community wiki is involved? this comment is apply for this kind of answer?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [answer based on Ubuntu wiki](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1052/answers-based-on-ubuntu-wiki?rq=1)